# Creating merged table cells using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can we use Bootstrap to create `<thead>` with 2 levels (eg: Summer Period has hildren data1, data2, data3) and also table cells that merged 2 vertical cells (eg:State)?

Here's how it looks like in Excel:

[image]

Comment: using `colspan="n"` for each cell, that should then add up the parent row full span

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly to do it with Bootstrap, but I know how to do it in HTML:

---

You can use a combination of the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, where `rowspan` is used for table headers spanning multiple **rows**, and the same applies to `colspan` and **columns**.

1. Break up your table headers into rows, according to their levels.
   So the first table row will consist of your "parent" headers, i.e. the headers that every other header and piece of data is going to fall under.
2. Your first row should have 3 columns: `State`, `Utilities Company` and `Summer Period`.
3. Add subsequent header rows for each level you drill down. Here, your next row will simply be the table headers for each data set.

---

Let's apply the attributes:

1. Your 1st `th` for *State* spans **2 rows**, so we add `rowspan="2"`.
2. The same applies to the next table header, *Utilities Company*.
3. *Summer Period* spans **1 row** and **3 columns**, so we add `colspan="3"`
4. Add another `tr` in the header, containing the 3 cells for *data1*, *data2* and *data3*.

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">State</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Utilities Company</th>
    <th colspan="3">Summer Period</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>data1</th>
    <th>data2</th>
    <th>data3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

---

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/JqC9s/48/).

Here's an updated demo (actually reset as base) including bootstrap.css even though it literally does nothing [demo fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/JqC9s/).

Comment: Very _to-the-point_ answer, but the formatting was kind of "uninviting". I gave it a make-over. Feel free to revert if you don't like it :)

Comment: Your example doesn't even import Bootstrap css. This isn't the solution for those wanting Bootstrap's fluid grid.

Answer (score 9):

Creating a complex header with multiple lines in Bootstrap is exactly as it is in HTML.  Here is your table in HTML for Bootstrap:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Utilities Company</th>
      <th colspan="3">Summer Period</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>data1</th>
      <th>data2</th>
      <th>data3</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  <tbody>
    ... data here ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You may have to add some CSS between your first and second header row to display your data correctly

Answer (score 3):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">State</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Utilities Company</th>
      <th colspan="3">Summer Period</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>data1</th>
      <th>data2</th>
      <th>data3</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  <tbody>
    ... data here ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're answering the same answer as **@albert**, if you wish you can edit his answer, not create your own. **Thanks!**